# Why string variable"<something" can't be output in php?

Tags: php

I was writing the code:
`<?PHP
$where='<something';
echo $where;
?>`
but it doesn't echo anything until I change the string $where to '< something'(add a space after "<"), why?

It might compile < to the begining of some markup language.

Comment: Doesn't echo, or doesn't *appear* to echo? Check the page source.

Comment: have you tried `"&lt;something"` instead?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.org/oUVy5M1D.

Comment: I think you're missing the "big picture" that you are writing a PHP script whose output is HTML that a browser will render/process.

Answer (score 1):

Less than `<` and greater than `>` signs are html entities or reserved symbols to denote html tags. To display them you need to use entity name or entity number. In case of "less than" they are < and  < respectively.

So change your code like this:

```
$where='&lt;someting'; echo $where;
```

or better yet

```
$where='&lt;someting'; echo htmlentities($where);
```

as correctly suggested by @Waleed Kahn.

Comment: Or better — `echo htmlentities($where)`.

Comment: u might want to explain why u did that. (considering that he even asked the question)

Answer (score 0):

In a browser, `<` introduces an HTML tag. If your string were `$where = "<img"` you'd probably end up with something like this:

[Image http://example.com/](http://example.com/)

Whenever you are outputting text, you should always either run `htmlentities`, `htmlspecialchars` or just `str_replace("<","&lt;",$where);` to escape HTML from being processed (the last one will still allow &characters;)

Answer (score 0):

It is because browsers treat the opening bracket, `<`, as an HTML tag. In the browser, right-click the page and select "View source".

If you have a terminal then you can use:

```
php -f file.php
```

That will output the raw content without parsing it.

If you want to see the code in your browser then you need to encode HTML characters using something like `htmlentities()`:

```
$where = '<something';
echo htmlentities($where); // &lt;something
```